# How can I set the font size to 20 so the items in the listBox will fit?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

This is the class where I draw and color the items in a listBox. The function is `ColorListBox`. If I'm using font size 8 it looks ok but if I'm using font size 20 the items in the listBox overlap each other; no space between them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    class ColorText
    {   
        public static void Texts(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }

        public static void ColorListBox(List<string> data, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            string strLeft = null;
            string strMid = "---";
            string strRight = null;

            if (data[e.Index].Contains(strMid))
            {
                int index = data[e.Index].IndexOf(strMid);
                strLeft = data[e.Index].Substring(0, index);
                strRight = data[e.Index].Substring(index + strMid.Length);
            }

            using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 20, FontStyle.Regular))
            {
                float startPos;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strLeft, f, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
                startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft, f).Width;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strMid, f, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
                startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft + strMid, f).Width;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strRight, f, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an image of how it looks when it's size 20:

[image]

Comment: So, you want to know how to change the padding on the text so that at font size 20, they don't overlap?  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try drawing the items in the ListBox yourself.

Set the DrawMode property of the ListBox to OwnerDrawVariable. Do this via Designer or via code:

```
myListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
```

Set up the ListBox events for DrawItem and MeasureItem. Do this via Designer or via code:

```
myListBox.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(DrawItem);
myListBox.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(MeasureItem);
```

This will allow you to be notified whenever the DrawItem and MeasureItem event is fired for each item in the ListBox.

Add event handlers for the events you are listening to. These will be populated automatically if you added them through the designer.

```
private void DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    // You'll change the font size here. Notice the 20
    e.Graphics.DrawString(data[e.Index],new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 20, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(color[e.Index]),e.Bounds);
}

private void MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    // You may need to experiment with the ItemHeight here..
    e.ItemHeight = 25;
}
```

Comment: moncadad all I needed is to change the mode in the designer to OwnerDrawVariable and then added this: listBox1_MeasureItem event and then : e.ItemHeight = 25; I didn't need to draw it or anything again since im doing it in the class above. Working perfect now thanks.

Comment: @user2065612 you're welcome. That's good that you only needed to listen to one event. Try experimenting with ItemHeight.. I just randomly chose 25 thinking it would be a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
listbox1.IntegralHeight=false; // where listbox1 is your listbox's ID
listbox1.Height=some_int_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.

What helped me is increasing ListBox.ItemHeight property after increasing the font size.